# regex how to match a newline with you a certain pattern after it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to check for all new lines that are not at the end of a string but not if they are followed by `Package`, I am using Notepad++.

As seen in the example below. I need to match the lines between the first sentence `without having to edit` and followed by `More information` `.` represents a new line in this file. But the new line followed by `Package:...` is perfectly fine and I want to ignore these.

```
.
without having to edit xorg.conf every time.

More information about X.Org can be found at:
<URL:http://www.X.org>
.
This package is built from the X.org xf86-input-vmmouse driver module.
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org>

Package: libxml-libxml-perl
Status: install ok installed
```

Is this possible?

```
 \n(?!\npackage)
```

I have tried this, which works to a point. But not for what I am after.

Comment: so you want to extract "More information about X.Org can be found at:
<URL:http://www.X.org>
.
This package is built from the X.org xf86-input-vmmouse driver module.
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org>"?

Comment: What language or text editor is being used for this?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I am not sure where these new lines will be. The above is just an example, the only thing that is constant is that there will be a new line followed by "Package". But also every single line has a trailing new line that matches `\n`

Comment: It will be with Notepad++

Comment: There appear to be no `\n` in your input string.

Comment: no new lines? every line has a line end doesn't it :/

Comment: When I pasted your text into N++, it shows only `\r` at the end of the lines.

Comment: i didn't use `\r` i used `\n`.....

Answer (score 0):

new line in windows is '\r\n' not '\n' so you have to consider this.

so you can do it by
    \r\n(?!\r\npackage)